# Cannot find -lSDL2

Tags: qt, qt-creator, sdl-2

I'm having errors in my Qt Creator where I'm editing my .pro file to link the library and include of SDL2. For some reason my errors say:

`:-1: error: cannot find -lSDL2`

`:-1: error: collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

What I did was: `Right click on my project -> Add Library -> External Library`, then this shows up:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwb8z.png)

I then added my library file of SDL2, which is `libSDL2.a` then added my include path and made sure Dynamic Linking is checked. Then I clicked `Next` and it showed me a snippet which will be added to the .pro file and clicked `Finish`.

My code works fine since it does detect SDL2, but the errors that I mentioned up there are occurring. What should I do?

This is the .pro file code:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++17

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    aerodesk.cpp

HEADERS += \
    aerodesk.h

FORMS += \
    aerodesk.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../SDL2-2.28.5/i686-w64-mingw32/release/ -lSDL2
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../SDL2-2.28.5/i686-w64-mingw32/debug/ -lSDL2
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../SDL2-2.28.5/i686-w64-mingw32/ -lSDL2

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../SDL2-2.28.5/i686-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../SDL2-2.28.5/i686-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2
```

Any help is appreciated!

I was expecting the program to run just fine without errors because I've successfully linked it until this happened.

This also goes the same when I try to add other linking other libraries too.

Comment: When you want to add a library search path you have to use [LIBS](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs) - [INCLUDEPATH](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmake-variable-reference.html#includepath) is for headers